# Creating a custom Image display in WPF as an optimization mechanism

Tags: c#, wpf, optimization, wpf-controls, custom-controls

I am doing some image processing on a custom class representing 16 bit gray-scale images.
The intensity of the pixels is stored in a single dimension ushort array: `ushort[] data` 
I also have the width, the height, the dpi, the stride, if necessary.

My motivation is the following: I show the results of certain operations quite fast, but the conversion from the array to the bitmapsource to the image object is too lengthy, so I was thinking of an Image object which drew its "source" directly from the array. I could thus write a method "update()" instead of doing multiple conversions.

1/ Is this possible?

2/ Would it be faster?

3/ How would I go about doing it?

The way I currently draw the image is with the following code (there's a bit more to that, but essetially that the heart of it)

```
BitmapSource bmps = BitmapSource.Create(Width, Height, Dpi, Dpi, PixelFormats.Gray16, null,
                                     data, stride); 
image.Source=bmps;
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using a separate array to store pixels and then creating a *BitmapSource* to show the results, I think it would be better using a **WriteableBitmap**, this way you can store pixel data (16-bit greyscale values) directly in its [BackBuffer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.writeablebitmap.backbuffer.aspx). Thus you can code something like this:

```
    // You create "bmp" just once and then update its content when needed
    var bmp = new WriteableBitmap(640, 480, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Gray16, null);
    var imgRect = new Int32Rect(0, 0, bmp.PixelWidth, bmp.PixelHeight);
```

Then you update the image:

```
    bmp.Lock();
    ApplySomeFilter(bmp.BackBuffer, ImageFilter.Blur);   // this is just an example ;)
    bmp.AddDirtyRect(imgRect);
    bmp.Unlock();
```

The *ApplySomeFilter* method can use **unsafe** code to modify pixel data of the *WriteableBitmap*.

---

For example, if *ApplySomeFilter* is defined like this:

```
    unsafe public void ApplySomeFilter(void* imgBuffer, ImageFilter filter)
    {
        // code that modifies pixels goes here
    }
```

then you can call it this way:

```
    ApplySomeFilter(bmp.BackBuffer.ToPointer(), ImageFilter.Blur);
```

Comment: Thank you! doesn't answer the question directly but provides a very nice workaround!

Comment: @EdwinG, if you prefer to use a separate array to store pixels information and updating the _BitmapSource_ (not creating a new _BitmapSource_ each time), you still can use a **WriteableBitmap** and dump the array to it using the method [WritePixels](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa346816.aspx).